# How to Log to Elastic Search by NLog or SeriLog with authentications

Tags: asp.net, elasticsearch, logstash, nlog, serilog

We are currently use azure scale set (many VMs on one source group with load balance and one availability set), we used to use NLog to log our web app action and errors, but now we asked/needs to use Elastic Search and also use centralized log for all azure vm instances instead of file per each instance.

I am new to ES and LogStash concepts, Do I need to replace NLog with something else? and How I move to use ES and unify all logs in one (I think to make nlog store in azure storage table as unify results  or do I needs to use LogStash or you prefer something else)?

What is the most logging that give support for .net core app on azure multi VMs as described above?

Any help please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you want to log into `ElasticSearch`, it's best if you use a Logging framework that supports Structured Logging which for [NLog] this feature is in <strike>beta</strike> **RTM**.

You can [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) as your Logging Framework which supports Structured Logging.

And there's also Serilog sink for ElasticSearch https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch

You should add these nuget packages to your project :

```
Serilog
Serilog.Sinks.ElasticSearch
```

This is a sample code for config of `Serilog` to sink to `ElasticSearch`

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
    {
        ModifyConnectionSettings = x => x.SetBasicAuthentication(username, password);
    })
    .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: That is a good answer, but what regarding store in azure table storage, can I make Serilog store in azure storage?

Comment: yes, you should use this Serilog Sink. https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-azuretablestorage,

Comment: Last Question Please: I use cloud.elastic.co, where I can provide UserName and Password inside Serilog?

Comment: you can set `ModifyConnectionSettings = x => x.SetBasicAuthentication(username, password);` in `ElasticsearchSinkOptions`

Comment: PS: NLog supports structured logging in NLog 4.5 which is RTM - https://github.com/NLog/NLog/releases/tag/v4.5

Comment: Thank you @Kahbazi It worked with me, I passed the user name and password with url, like this:                                                                   
 http :// MyUserName:Password@ElasticURl:port

Answer (score 27):

For NLog there is a target "NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch" ([nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch))
which uses the Elasticsearch.Net package.

Usage:

```xml
<nlog>
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch"/>
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target name="elastic" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" flushTimeout="5000">
      <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch"  
         requireAuth="true"
         username="myUserName"
         password="coolpassword"/>
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="elastic" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Docs for the parameters: https://github.com/ReactiveMarkets/NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch/wiki

Please note:

- If you need to use Elasticsearch.Net 6 (equivalent to Elastic Search version 6 or later), you need NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch version 5.
- For Elasticsearch.Net 5 you need to use NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch 4

Comment: Thank you @Julian where is to add user name and password? do you have any working sample? I am using cloud.elastic.co and need to provide username and password

Comment: Hi! I've updated the example and added a link to all the parameters

Comment: Thank you @Julian it is working, and your note about Elasticsearch.Net nuget version is very important, Thanks for answer and for details.

Answer (score 10):

Many recommends that the application should not write directly to ElasticSearch, but should just write to local files.

Then have a service (Ex. FileBeat) to upload the contents of the log-files into ElasticSearch.

This will optimize network traffic to the ElasticSearch instance (bulk), and will ensure logging is not lost if problems with the network or ElasticSearch instance is restarted because of maintenance.

Comment: I also have multi instances on cloud/azure with load balance between them, is that could cause any problem?

Comment: send logs through the network (Elastic), and fallback to file (when the network is unavailable). In addition, it is nice to notify the administrator, when the app can't send messages through the network.

Comment: Sometimes this isn't practical, like when there are two departments in the company logging different stuff, each with separate LogStash instances. (E.g. in our org we have Security sending IIS logs to their LogStash, and we want to start sending application logs to our LogStash.) Beats can't duplicate output and you can't have more than one instance of each kind of Beat per server.

Answer (score 1):

SetBasicAuthentication is not longer used. BasicAuthentication is the new thing you should use.

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
    {
        ....
        ModifyConnectionSettings = x => x.BasicAuthentication("elasticUsername", "elasticPassword"),
    })
    .CreateLogger();
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/configuration-options.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Nlog to write your logs into Elastic, you can follow this approach, first add the Auth settings into your target file:

```
requireAuth="true"
username="*******"
password="********"
```

After you added these attributes to the target tag in nlog.config everything will work well. But the other issue may be you face is the SSL connection problem. If your Elastic endpoint has SSL.

One solution to fix this issue is disabling certificate validation on Elastic endpoint. To achieve this, you need to add another attribute to your Elastic target.

```
DisableCertificateValidation="true"
```

Now your Elastic target in nlog.config file should be something like this:

```
<target xsi:type="ElasticSearch" 
    name="elastic"               
    index="MyService-${date:format=yyyy.MM.dd}" 
    layout ="MyService-|${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" 
    includeAllProperties="true"
    requireAuth="true" 
    username="*******"
    password="*********" 
    uri="https://elasticSampleaddress.com:9200" />
```

For more detail, you can also read my article about this problem :[Writing logs into Elastic with NLog , ELK, and .Net 5.0](https://medium.com/@m.qafouri/writing-logs-into-elastic-with-nlog-elk-and-net-5-0-part-2-50177d05e173)