# Is there any way to log data in virtual machine's elasticsearch using nlog and .netcore

Tags: elasticsearch, asp.net-core, nlog

I have install elasticsearch, kibana in azure virtual machine and trying to log the data in elasticsearch from my local porject using Nlog and asp.netcore. Is there any way to log the data in virtual machine elasticsearch. I am able to log the data in locally installed elasticsearch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Log to Elastic Search by NLog or SeriLog with authentications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49595422/how-to-log-to-elastic-search-by-nlog-or-serilog-with-authentications)

Comment: I go the solution using this link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49595422/how-to-log-to-elastic-search-by-nlog-or-serilog-with-authentications. And i add one more parameter uri in target element. <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch"
              uri ="http://pubilcIP:9200"
              requireAuth="true"
         username=""
         password=""/>